# .Net Core 3 IStringLocalizer.WithCulture(CultureInfo) is obsolete

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

I've upgraded a project from .Net Core 2.2 to .Net Core 3.0.

After trying to fix all the warnings and errors I'm now trying to find a solution to this warning:

```
'IStringLocalizer.WithCulture(CultureInfo)' is obsolete: 'This method is obsolete.
 Use `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` instead.'
```

I'm using this to change the website language per the logged-in user.
I have this implementation to change the website culture per user:

```
public class CultureLocalizer : ICultureLocalizer
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer localizer;
    public CultureLocalizer(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
    {
        var type = typeof(Resources.PageResources);
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
        localizer = factory.Create("PageResources", assemblyName.Name);
    }

    // if we have formatted string we can provide arguments         
    // e.g.: @Localizer.Text("Hello {0}", User.Name)
    public LocalizedString Get(string key, params string[] arguments)
    {
        return arguments == null ? localizer[key] : localizer[key, arguments];
    }

    public LocalizedString Get(Enum key, params string[] arguments)
    {
        return arguments == null ? localizer[key.ToString()] : localizer[key.ToString(), arguments];
    }

    public LocalizedString Get(CultureInfo culture, string key, params string[] arguments)
    {
        // This is obsolete
        return arguments == null ? localizer.WithCulture(culture)[key] : localizer.WithCulture(culture)[key, arguments];
    }

    public LocalizedString Get(CultureInfo culture, Enum key, params string[] arguments)
    {
        // This is obsolete
        return arguments == null ? localizer.WithCulture(culture)[key.ToString()] : localizer.WithCulture(culture)[key.ToString(), arguments];
    }
}
```

And this is the dummy class which only holds the `.resx` file for the translations:

```
// dummy class for grouping localization resources
public class PageResources
{
}
```

I couldn't find anything on the web that refers to how to solve this warning except for this [discussion on github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/36397) that appears to have no solution yet.

Had anyone else stumbled upon this warning and found a solution for it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Reading accepted answer, I'm not sure how that addresses what I *think* you are asking.  In my case, I'm needing to write my own `ViewLocalizer` so I started from Microsoft's implementation from Github and it still has the `WithCulture` method in there so I'm wondering how I should resolve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is already mention in there source code [here](https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.Abstractions/IStringLocalizer.cs,72b097d10c2d7ada)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new <see cref="IStringLocalizer"/> for a specific <see cref="CultureInfo"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="culture">The <see cref="CultureInfo"/> to use.</param>
    /// <returns>A culture-specific <see cref="IStringLocalizer"/>.</returns>
    [Obsolete("This method is obsolete. Use `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` instead.")]
    IStringLocalizer WithCulture(CultureInfo culture);
```

Here is how they use in [.Net Core 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture?view=netcore-3.0)

```
public static void Main()  
   {
      // Display the name of the current thread culture.
      Console.WriteLine("CurrentCulture is {0}.", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);

      // Change the current culture to th-TH.
      CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("th-TH", false);
      Console.WriteLine("CurrentCulture is now {0}.", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);

      // Display the name of the current UI culture.
      Console.WriteLine("CurrentUICulture is {0}.", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);

      // Change the current UI culture to ja-JP.
      CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo( "ja-JP", false );
      Console.WriteLine("CurrentUICulture is now {0}.", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);
   }
```

Update: This approach is work around until we can have offical announcement from Microsoft

You can create a service like this

```
public class LocalizationService
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;

        public LocalizationService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
        {
            var type = typeof(SharedResource);
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
            _localizer = factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
        }

        public LocalizedString GetLocalizedHtmlString(string key)
        {
            return _localizer[key];
        }
    }
```

Then in your startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<LocalizationService>();
            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new[]
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en"),
                    new CultureInfo("nl")
                };

                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en", uiCulture: "en");
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
                {
                    options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                    {
                        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
                        return factory.Create("SharedResource", assemblyName.Name);
                    };
                });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            var localizationOption = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOption.Value);

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

You can view my full code [here](https://github.com/ngohungphuc/Research/tree/master/ASP.Net/Localization/Localization)

Comment: I've updated my question with the code that I'm using. Could you please have a look at it? Because it doesn't look compatible with your solution.

Comment: @LiranFriedman where do you get ICultureLocalizer ? I'm try to search for that interface but I cant find it

Comment: Could you please explain how does the culture changes per user? Each user selects his/her preferred language in his profile. Also, how could I check to see that it works?

Comment: For those who use this in a console app - it is important to use `CurrentUICulture` because `CurrentCulture` seems to have no effect on `StringLocalizer`. If using in a web app, you can use `services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>` to adjust behavior for detecting current user's request language, but be aware of Microsoft defaults - headers, cookies, whatever - for automatic language detection. For this reason I prefer to adjust `RequestCultureProviders` to my own known mechanism for detecting user's language.

Comment: @tony-ngo Do you know of an update to this approach for dotnet 6?

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061622/71376) shows how to get the list of default supported cultures.