# Changing the language of an IStringLocalizer

Tags: c#, .net-core, internationalization

I am attempting to dynamically set the language of an `IStringLocalizer` at run time. The only available method that seems to do this is `IStringLocalizer.WithCulture`. However, attempting to use it results in a deprecation warning.

```
public IStringLocalizer GetLocalizer(string locale) {
    this.localizerFactory.Create(typeof(CommonResources)).WithCulture(new CultureInfo(locale));
}
```

I am ***not*** using ASP, I am doing this in an `IHostedService` that handles user interaction from another source (various web chat APIs). This service needs to conform to the language set for the chat server or channel by the admins (stored in database).

What is the correct, current way of setting the language of an `IStringLocalizer`? Should I use another class entirely?

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316533/net-core-3-istringlocalizer-withculturecultureinfo-is-obsolete) SO answer help you?

Comment: @SimonWilson Unfornutately, no. In the answer they only seem to provide languages at the start of the application, in the form of a default value and a collection of available values. If they programmatically set the lagnuage of the `IStringLocalizer`, it is very well hidden. Moreover, the example is for ASP applications, which is not my case.

Comment: Moreover, in a comment the OP themselves ask how the provided answer changes the cuture dynamically.

Comment: probably you can create a middleware that, based on every request can set the currentCulture or the UICulture. The localizer would automatically resolve the string based on the culture set.

Answer (score 19):

This should do it. You need to set `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` to the culture you want before getting the string value.

```
    private string GetStringValue(string stringName, string culture)
    {
        var specifiedCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = specifiedCulture;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = specifiedCulture;
        var options = Options.Create(new LocalizationOptions { ResourcesPath = "Resources" });
        var factory = new ResourceManagerStringLocalizerFactory(options, new LoggerFactory());
        var localizer = new StringLocalizer<RecipeController>(factory);
        return localizer[stringName];
    }
```

If you have an instance of `IStringLocalizer` you can use it instead of creating a new one.

Comment: There used to be method IStringLocalizer.WithCulture but it's now obsolete. To set  CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture is recommended solution from Microsoft documentation.

Comment: The answer seems correct to me. The comment from @LukášKmoch may be correct (I did not find such documentation), but I noticed that CurrentCulture does not do any difference on this scenario. CurrentUICulture seems to be the main thing to be set.

Comment: @JoaoRibeiro `CurrentCulture` will impact currency, date/time and number conversions. `CurrentUICulture` will control which string that is being looked up. Say you had the localized string TOTAL_AMOUNT `"The total amount is {0:C}"`. Then you will need to set both in order for `StringLocalizer["TOTAL_AMOUNT", endOfYearAmount]` to ensure both the string and the currency argument is displayed correctly.

Comment: I don’t have much experience with CultureInfo, is it thread-safe to set CultureInfo.CurrentCulture and CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture? At first glance it appears as though you are setting a static property and thus the change would affect all threads at once.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `IStringLocalizer` is implemented on `ResourceManagerStringLocalizer` setting `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` is the only way to change the culture on the fly.

```cs
IStringLocalizer Localizer = ServiceHelper.GetService<IStringLocalizer<AppStrings>>();
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var HelloEN = Localizer["Hello"];
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
var HelloFR = Localizer["Hello"];
```

However, the automatically generated ResX file has `ResourceManager` which it access with either `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` or its local `Culture` static member. Here's a demonstration of both:

```cs
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var HelloEN = AppStrings.Hello;
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
var HelloFR = AppStrings.Hello;
AppString.Culture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
var HelloES = AppStrings.Hello;
```

The current `ResourceManagerStringLocalizer` is unaware of the `AppStrings.Culture` property, so, you cannot use it with `ResrouceManagerStringLocalizer`.

A solution is to build your own using reflection to retrieve the `Culture` and `ResourceManager` from the ResX:

```cs
public class ResourceStringLocalizer<TStringResource> : IStringLocalizer
{
    private Type _stringResource;
    private PropertyInfo _cultureProperty;
    private PropertyInfo _resourceManagerProperty;
    private ResourceManager _resourceManager;

    private CultureInfo Culture
        => _cultureProperty?.GetValue(null) as CultureInfo;

    public IEnumerable<LocalizedString> GetAllStrings(bool includeParentCultures)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public LocalizedString this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            if (name == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            }
            var value = _resourceManager?.GetString(name, Culture);
            return new LocalizedString(name, value ?? name, resourceNotFound: value == null);
        }
    }

    public LocalizedString this[string name, params object[] arguments]
    {
        get
        {
            if (name == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            }
            var format = _resourceManager?.GetString(name, Culture);
            var value = string.Format(format ?? name, arguments);
            return new LocalizedString(name, value ?? name, resourceNotFound: value == null);
        }
    }

    public ResourceStringLocalizer()
    {
        _stringResource = typeof(TStringResource);
        _cultureProperty = _stringResource?.GetProperty("Culture", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        _resourceManagerProperty = _stringResource?.GetProperty("ResourceManager", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        _resourceManager = _resourceManagerProperty?.GetValue(null) as ResourceManager;
    }
}
```

Here's a demo of the above class:

```cs
IStringLocalizer Localizer = new ResourceStringLocalizer<AppStrings>();
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var HelloEN = Localizer["Hello"];
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
var HelloFR = Localizer["Hello"];
AppStrings.Culture = new CultureInfo("es-ES");
var HelloES = Localizer["Hello"];
```

Answer (score -4):

you may write your own culture middleware which can set the culture based on the user or maybe using the Http Header [Accept-Language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language)

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(roptions =>
        {
            IList<CultureInfo> supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
                new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                new CultureInfo("fr"),
            };
            roptions.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
            roptions.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            roptions.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            roptions.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new YourCustomCultureProvider());
        });
```

Sample Middleware

```
public class YourCustomCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
{
    public override Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));


        var culture = //Some Logic

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
        {
            // No values specified for either so no match
            return Task.FromResult((ProviderCultureResult)null);
        }

        var requestCulture = new ProviderCultureResult(culture);

        return Task.FromResult(requestCulture);
    }
}
```

Refer this link if it could help you - https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-localization-deep-dive

Comment: There is no HTTP at all. As I said I'm using webchat APIs such as [Discord.Net](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net). I am ***not*** using ASP, this is ***not*** a web app. Moreover your solution doesn't provide a way to pass any object to the culture provider when creating the localizer, it can only recieve objects when configuring the app.