# What is the dotnet 6 equivalent of localizer.WithCulture?

Tags: c#, localization, .net-6.0, currentculture, migrating

When my project was using

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

I could get the localization injected in my page constructor:

```
IStringLocalizer<Strings> _localizer;

public IndexModel(IStringLocalizer<Strings> localizer) {
    _localizer = localizer;
}
```

but still retrieve an alternative language's collection of strings:

```
var localizer = _localizer.WithCulture(new CultureInfo(cultureCode));
var translatedStr = localizer[c.Value].ToString();
```

Being in the process of upgrading to:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

The `_localizer.WithCulture` code shows this error in VS Code:

```
'IStringLocalizer<Strings>' does not contain a definition for 'WithCulture' and no accessible extension method 'WithCulture' accepting a first argument of type 'IStringLocalizer<Strings>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What is the dotnet 6 version of this?

If I switch back to `netcoreapp3.1` I can clearly see the warning:

```
'IStringLocalizer.WithCulture(CultureInfo)' is obsolete: 'This method is obsolete. Use `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` instead.'
```

But what are the `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` it is referring to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Core 3 IStringLocalizer.WithCulture(CultureInfo) is obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316533/net-core-3-istringlocalizer-withculturecultureinfo-is-obsolete)